# std::move a stack object (to a different thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, rvalue-reference

So there are two things that I'm not sure.

1. If I do something like this:

   ```
   void sendToDifferentThread(SomeClass &&obj);
   ...
   {
       SomeClass object;
       sendToDifferentThread(std::move(object));
   }
   ```

What will happen? How can there ever only be one copy of `object` if it's created on the stack, since when we go out of the enclosing scope everything on stack is destroyed?

2. If I do something like this:

   ```
   SomeClass object;
   doSomethingOnSameThread(std::move(object));
   ```

What will happen if I do something in the current scope to `object` later? It was "moved away" to some other function, so did the current function "lose" ownership of it in some way?

Comment: If you bind a reference to an object, it is *your* responsibility to ensure that the object lives as long as anyone uses the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ when an object is constructed, memory is allocated at the same time. If the constructor runs to completion (without throwing) then the object is "alive". At some point if it is a stack object and goes out of scope, or its a heap object and you call delete, its destructor is called and that original memory is freed, and then the object is "dead". C++11 std::move / move constructors don't change any of this. What a move constructor does is give you a way and a simple syntax to "destructively" copy objects.

For instance if you move construct from a `std::vector<int>`, instead of reading all the `int`s and copying them, it will copy the pointer and the size count instead to the new vector, and set the old pointer to a nullptr and size to 0 (or possibly, allocate a (tiny) new vector of minimal size... depends on implementation). Basically when you move from something you have to leave it in a "valid", "alive" state -- it's not "dead" after you move from it, and the destructor is still going to be called later. It didn't "move" in the sense that it's still following the same lifetime and now it's just "somewhere else in memory". When you "move" from an object, there are definitely two different objects involved from C++'s point of view and I don't think you can make sense of it after a certain point if you try to think of it as though there's only one object that exists in that scenario.

Comment: So there are actually two different objects in the memory but they _conceptually_ represent the same entity (share the same state)? (and it's the move constructor's responsibility to ensure that?)

Comment: Yeah, at least the way I think about it, what the move constructor does is, it's like the copy constructor, but when it copies it "pilfers" the resources. So the original vector ends up empty. Not *dead*, it's dtor is still going to happen later, but for now it is impoverished. IIUC it's always the case in C++XX that e.g. if I make a local variable in some function, of class type, then when we leave that function some dtor is going to be called for that class with that same "this" pointer value, no matter what, even if exception is thrown. (Unless like std::terminate is involved or something.)

Comment: Wait, they don't share the same state, if an object is move constructed, then (most likely) only the newly constructed object has the "content"    think about `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I guess I should qualify my "no matter what" as follows. IIUC, when the program is running "normally", and even during exception handling, destructors are always called. If the program terminates abnormally (`std::terminate()`, `throw 42`, ...) then they will not / might not be called. If your destructors start throwing exceptions themselves, then in various scenarios its possible that your program will recover and proceed normally after having skipped some destructors. But basically you should never do that, and in C++11 typically you have to write a lot of boiler plate just to permit that.

Comment: @RussellGreene Yeah actually what I wanted to say is that the new object now has the same state as the moved one _before_ getting moved.

Comment: @zizheng OK that makes sense